# rust split debuginfo binary is still large

Tags: rust

I'm using `rust:1.67-buster` to build my mixed Rust/C++ project in docker, for running on Debian.

When compiling a release with no debuginfo, my binary on Linux is 18mb. When I set
`ENV RUSTFLAGS="-C link-args=-lstdc++ -C debuginfo=2 -C split-debuginfo=packed`

I get `dwp` files inside the `deps` directory, and the executable is also 96mb.

If I remove even `split-debuginfo`, the binary goes up to 145mb, so it's doing *something*. But that still seems awfully large.

If I add `-C strip=debuginfo` then my executable size goes down to 9mb and I still have the `dwp` files in the `deps/` subdirectory, but obviously gdb doesn't know where to look for them.

Isn't the point of `-C split-debuginfo=packed` that I shouldn't need the extra `strip` command?

Comment: I've read [the documentation about `split-debuginfo`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/codegen-options/index.html#split-debuginfo), and it doesn't really mention not including debug info in the binary. It's just about producing debug information outside of the binary.

Comment: Sounds like you want the [`strip` profile option](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html#strip)?